# How to omit row but keep the frequencies with gtsummary in R?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm using the gtsummary package to elaborate a simple table. The code I'm using is the following

```
dados %>% select(ANO_OCORRENCIA, FAIXA_ETARIA, CS_RACA, ORIENT_SEX, IDENT_GEN, CAT_GEST) %>%
    tbl_summary(by = ANO_OCORRENCIA,
              digits = all_categorical() ~ c(0,1),
              label = list(FAIXA_ETARIA ~ "Faixa Etária",
                           CS_RACA ~ "Raça/cor da pele**",
                           ORIENT_SEX ~ "Orientação Sexual",
                           IDENT_GEN ~ "Identidade de Gênero",
                           CAT_GEST ~ "Gestantes")) %>%
    modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Ano de Ocorrência**") %>%
    add_overall() %>%
    modify_header(update = list( label ~ '**Características**',
                               stat_0  ~ '**Total**<br>N = 4,251' )) %>%
  modify_table_body(~.x %>% dplyr::relocate(stat_0, .after = stat_6),
                    filter, !(variable == "Gestantes" & label == "Não Gestante"))
```

The result:

[image]

I want to omit the row highlighted in red, so it doesn't change the frequencies. I've tried `filter, !(variable == "Gestantes" & label == "Não Gestante")` but it doesn't work. When I change `variable == "Gestantes"` to `variable == "CS_GEST"`, an error message appears:

```
Error: An error occured in `add_overall()`, and overall statistics cannot be merged.
Has the variable label changed since the original call of `tbl_summary()`?
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here an example with `mtcars` data from the `datasets` package

```
mtcars%>%
  select(mpg,cyl)%>%
  tbl_summary()%>%
   remove_row_type(variables = cyl,
                   type="level",
                   level_value = "8")
```

[image: gt remove]

For ref the original table without removing the row

```
mtcars%>%
  select(mpg,cyl)%>%
  tbl_summary()
```

[image: ref]

You could find more detail here
[remove_row_type](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/remove_row_type.html)