# Is there a way to look only at a specific level of a factor variable in tbl_summary?

Tags: r, survey, weighted, gtsummary

I'm trying to compare and get the p-values for factor variables, stratified by trt/control.

For reproducibility, this is a simplified version of how I loaded my data:

```
# DEMO
demo <- nhanes('DEMO')
demo_vars <- names(demo)
demo2 <- nhanesTranslate('DEMO', demo_vars, data = demo)

# PRESCRIPTION MEDICATIONS
rxq_rx <- nhanes('RXQ_RX')
rxq_rx_vars <- names(rxq_rx)
rxq_rx2 <- nhanesTranslate('RXQ_RX', rxq_rx_vars, data = rxq_rx)
rxq_rx2 <- rxq_rx2 %>% select("SEQN", "RXD240B") %>% filter(!is.na(RXD240B)) %>% group_by(SEQN) %>% dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), ~toString(na.omit(.))))

nhanesAnalysis = join_all(list(demo2, rxq_rx2), by = "SEQN", type = "full")

# Reconstructing survey weights for combining 1999-2018 - Combining ten survey cycles (twenty years) 
nhanesAnalysis$wtint20yr <- ifelse(nhanesAnalysis$SDDSRVYR %in% c(1,2), (2/10 * nhanesAnalysis$WTINT4YR), # for 1999-2002
                                          (1/10 * nhanesAnalysis$WTINT2YR)) # for 2003-2018


# sample weights 
nhanesDesign <- svydesign(id      = ~SDMVPSU,
                          strata  = ~SDMVSTRA,
                          weights = ~wtint20yr,
                          nest    = TRUE,
                          data    = nhanesAnalysis)

# subset
obese_adults  <- subset(nhanesDesign, (obesity == 1 & !is.na(BMXBMI) & RIDAGEYR >= 60))
```

I am using the following tbl_summary() function to get this table.

```
  ageDesign %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = obesity,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>% tbl_svysummary(
        by = wlp_yn,
        percent = "row",
        include = c(phys_func2, standing_chair)
      )%>%
      add_overall() %>%
      add_p()
  )
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLCQ2.png)

I want to look only at the "difficulty" level of the factor "standing_chair". Is there a way I can do this? Thank you!

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75749259/how-to-omit-row-but-keep-the-frequencies-with-gtsummary-in-r/

Comment: Thank you @Wael! Just one more thing -- I'm confused on how to adjust the p-values accordingly? I think it's still reflecting all levels of the factor.

Comment: I didn't test it in your data, but in tbl_summary the % and freq counts are not changed.
could you verify and share your feedback?

Comment: Just verified the p-values stay the same. I'm not sure if I'm missing something but I am hoping to get p-values for differences in the 0 and 1 subgroups (i.e. the "by = wlp_yn" arg.). The % and freq counts remain unchanged but I am assuming the p-values should change? TIA @Wael!